# Set Value on Select Tag using URL String with PHP

Tags: php, forms, select, query-string

I am attempting to create a form with multiple text feilds, drop downs, and check boxes that then gets processed through some php to output a header which propagates the url with some of the inputted variables. This would then put you to a page with those same fields and some additional ones for more information. I would like the previously inputted options to be loaded already. I have created a simplified version of what I am working on below to better explain.

HTML Form - Page One

```
<form name="get_rate" method="POST" action="process.php">

<input name="dollar_amount" type="text" placeholder="Dollar Amount">

<select name="loan_purpose">
<option value="1">Purchase</option>
<option value="2">Cash Out</option>
<option value="3">Other</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="39"> <label>Agree</label>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"  name="submit">

</form>
```

Process PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && strlen($_POST['dollar_amount'])>0) {

   header('Location: quote/?post=1&16='.$_POST['dollar_amount'].'&17='.$_POST['loan_purpose']);
}
else{
    header('Location: mortgage-quote/');
    }
?>
```

Which will out put something like this 
/quote/?post=1&16=[DOLLAR AMOUNT]&17=[OPTION]

And land you on a page with a form like this

```
<form name="mortgage_rate" method="POST" action="process.php">
<input name="dollar_amount" type="text" placeholder="Dollar Amount" value="<?php echo $_GET['16']; ?>">

<select name="loan_purpose" value="<?php echo $_GET['17']; ?>">
<option value="1">Purchase</option>
<option value="2">Cash Out</option>
<option value="3">Other</option>
</select>

</form>
```

The text field works just fine grabbing the value from the url and putting it into the value, but it gets more tricky with select tags.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of this ended up working.

```
<option value="1" <?php if($_GET['17'] == 1){ echo"selected";} ?>>Purchase</option>
```

Not the most clever solution, but it works.